# Deployment synchronization commit for tenant -1234 failed WSO2 IS 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am running WSO2 IS 5.0.0. I have the SP for IS 5.0.0 applied along with all the other security patches issued for that version for Identity Server and Carbon 4.2.0. My environment consists of 4 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).
I am constantly receiving in the console log files "Deployment synchronization commit for tenant -1234 failed". After I applied the changes that @ycr proposed in order to disable the Dep-Sync:

```
  <DeploymentSynchronizer>
<Enabled>false</Enabled>
<AutoCommit>false</AutoCommit>
<AutoCheckout>false</AutoCheckout>
<RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
<SvnUrl>http://svnrepo.example.com/repos/</SvnUrl>
<SvnUser>username</SvnUser>
<SvnPassword>password</SvnPassword>
<SvnUrlAppendTenantId>false</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
```

and restarted all of my machines. I had no issues for about 2 weeks. Then suddenly I received the the same error but with additional stack trace on two of my machines today (29.09.2016):

```
    [2016-09-29 04:42:24,000] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask} -  Deployment synchronization commit for tenant -1234 failed
com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: No response for 120000 ms. Aborting invocation! InvocationFuture{invocation=BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=GetOperation{}, partitionId=247, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[172.31.2.242]:4000}, done=false} No response has been send  backups-expected: 0 backups-completed: 0 reinvocations: 0
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.newOperationTimeoutException(BasicInvocation.java:782)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.waitForResponse(BasicInvocation.java:760)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:697)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:676)
at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:257)
at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:161)
at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:53)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastDistributedMapProvider$DistMap.get(HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:130)
at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:182)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCPathCache.getPathID(JDBCPathCache.java:299)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.getResourceID(JDBCResourceDAO.java:81)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.resourceExists(JDBCResourceDAO.java:151)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.resourceExists(Repository.java:134)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:644)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:293)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:777)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:60)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:760)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:757)
at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.getDeploymentSyncConfigurationFromRegistry(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:262)
at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.getActiveSynchronizerConfiguration(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:108)
at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.commit(DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.java:96)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.deploymentSyncCommit(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:207)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:128)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.resolveResponse(BasicInvocation.java:862)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.resolveResponseOrThrowException(BasicInvocation.java:795)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:698)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:676)
at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:257)
at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:161)
at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:53)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastDistributedMapProvider$DistMap.get(HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:130)
at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:182)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCPathCache.getPathID(JDBCPathCache.java:299)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.getResourceID(JDBCResourceDAO.java:81)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.resourceExists(JDBCResourceDAO.java:151)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.resourceExists(Repository.java:134)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:644)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:293)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:777)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:60)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:760)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:757)
at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.getDeploymentSyncConfigurationFromRegistry(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:262)
at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.getActiveSynchronizerConfiguration(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:108)
at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.commit(DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.java:96)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.deploymentSyncCommit(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:207)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:128)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Are there any other configuration files that I need to tweak?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any secondary user stores? If not you do not need Dep-sync. You can simply disable it. If you are using Secondary user stores the best option is to avoid using Dep-sync and copy secondary user store related configurations manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently I am not using secondary user stored. I updated the following elements in order to apply your proposal:  
  <DeploymentSynchronizer>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <AutoCommit>false</AutoCommit>
    <AutoCheckout>false</AutoCheckout>
    <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
    <SvnUrl>http://svnrepo.example.com/repos/</SvnUrl>
    <SvnUser>username</SvnUser>
    <SvnPassword>password</SvnPassword>
    <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>false</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
  </DeploymentSynchronizer>
  I am going to closely monitor the system for this type of error.

Comment: I updated the post. Long story short - I applied the proposed changes to disable Dep-Sync and had no issues for about two weeks. Then suddenly the issue appeared again on two of my machines, but with additional stack trace. Do you have any other suggestions?